# Python - NameError: name 'search_fixture' is not defined

Tags: python

I am making a program here and I get the error. How to fix it as I have defined the function but it says I haven't?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Practice Program/Task3 Practice/Task3_Own_copy.py", line 19, in <module>
    menu()
  File "G:/Practice Program/Task3 Practice/Task3_Own_copy.py", line 9, in menu
    search_fixture()
```

NameError: name 'search_fixture' is not defined

```
 def menu():
            print("\n\nWelcome to the fixture manager")
            print("\nWould you like to:\n\nOption A\tSearch for a fixture\nOption B\tOutstanding fixtures"
              "\nOption C\tDisplay leader board\n\nEnter Q to quit\n\nPlease enter A,B,C, or Q\n")
    
            choice = input(">>>").upper()
    
            if choice == "A":
                search_fixture()
            elif choice == "B":
                print("Yolo")
            elif choice == "C":
                print("Yolo")
            elif choice == "Q":
                print("\nThank you for using the tracker program, goodbye.\n")
                quit()
            else:
                menu()
    menu()
    
    
    
    def search_fixture():
        
        found = False
        search = input("\n\nPlease enter a fixture number:")
    
        with open("firesideFixtures.txt","r") as f:
            for line in f:
                fixtureNumber,fixtureDate,fixtureTime,player1Nickname,player2Nickname,fixturePlayed,winningNickname = line.split(",")
    
                if fixtureNumber.upper() == search.upper():
                    found = True
                    print("\nFixutre Number:",fixtureNumber,"\nFixture Date:",fixtureDate,
                          "\nFixture Time:",fixtureTime,"\nPlayer 1 Nickname:",
                          player1Nickname,"\nPlayer 2 Nickname:",player2Nickname,
                          "\nFixture Played:",fixturePlayed,"\nWinning Nickname:"
                          ,winningNickname,"\n")
    
                if found == False:
                    print("\n There were no results for:",search,". Please search for another fixture")
                    search_fixture()
    search_fixture()
```

Comment: For your information guys, both of these functions are in line but it's formatted strange on here.

Comment: indentation may be the key to your issue so please make an effort format that as you get it on your computer.

Comment: The issue is `if choice == "A":` in `menu()`. At the point the interpreter hits that line, `search_fixture` is not defined... going top-to-bottom through the code.

Comment: In future, if you want to post code, just copy/paste the whole thing as 1 chunk, highlight it all, and hit `CTRL`+`k` or click the `{}` button in the editor. It will sort the formatting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python (and most other languages) execute from top to bottom. If you are defining FunctionA ( that is calling another FunctionB that hasnt been defined yet) and then calling the FunctionA, you are attempting to call FunctionB indirectly, which hasnt been defined.

This is what you are doing:

```
def FunctionA():
    FunctionB()
FunctionA()

def FunctionB():
    print("inside of B")
FunctionB()
```

This will cause the error because from top to bottom, it doesn't know what `FunctionB()` is by the time it gets to it because it hasn't been defined yet.

Typically single file python programs are going to define all of the functions first, and then call them.

Something like this is what you want:

```
def FunctionA():
    FunctionB()
def FunctionB():
    print("inside of B")

FunctionA()
FunctionB()
```

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/9300/commonwealth-exceptions/28947/nameerror-name-is-not-defined#t=201703092152132085722 for future reference

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the indentation is correct as you stated, the problem is the way the Python interprets the file. It defines the functions as it reads them. In your case, it's trying to access the search_fixture() function, but it hasn't gotten to it yet, so it's not defined.

Swap the order of the functions, and your problem should be solved. I tried copying and pasting your code, reproduced the problem, moved the search_fixture definition so it was before Menu, and it worked.

Comment: I appreciate that however, I need the question prompt first

Comment: @Hayden Then you need to refactor your code. There is no other way to reasonably do what you want to do.

Comment: If search_fixture doesn't need to call menu again, you could just leave the call to search_fixture() at the bottom of the file. Move only the function definition. 

However, if you need to have them call each other (maybe bring the menu up after search_fixture is done), then you'll be better off turning it into a class. Then, the order of methods doesn't matter and they can call each other.